# TSQL How can I group by literals?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I'm reducing this problem to a very simple form:

```
SELECT
'A' AS [Literal]
UNION 
SELECT
'B' AS [Literal]
GROUP BY
[Literal]
```

I get the message:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
>   Invalid column name 'Literal'.

I tried this with the same results:

```
SELECT
t.literal FROM 
(SELECT 'A' AS [Literal]) t
UNION 
SELECT
'B' 
GROUP BY
[Literal]
```

Comment: Do you have other columns or only this one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a derived table when you want to `GROUP BY` a `UNION`:

```
SELECT X.[Literal], [Count] = COUNT(*)
FROM(
    SELECT [Literal] = 'A'
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT [Literal] = 'B'
) X
GROUP BY X.[Literal]
```

[Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/15438)

Answer (score 1):

You can use cte...

```
;WITH cte AS (
 SELECT
 'A' AS [Literal]
 UNION 
 SELECT
 'B' AS [Literal])
SELECT [Literal]
FROM cte
GROUP BY [Literal]
```

Comment: No, this is wrong. This is what the OP had and does not work. The `GROUP BY` is applied to the second Select only.

Comment: Well, if the first one was a mistake, you could simply edit it out.

Comment: I thought it would be plain lame to do it like that... :P

Comment: Why, editing isn't merely for adding new bits and apologising for the old ones. :)